# How do I programmatically install an apk from a storage device when storage device is inserted into android tablet?

Tags: android, adb

We have an android tablet in production (rk3288 running android 5.1). How do I install a new apk on a rooted tablet when a storage device is inserted? We need to be able to send a flash drive to customers who need a fresh install.

I've been looking for a way to run the adb shell installation command when a storage device is detected, but can't seem to find a comprehensive way to do so.

Comment: USB mounts are always `NOEXEC` and there's no autorun. Consider a standard method.

Comment: If you want to trigger an app installation from within the device the component that performs the installation has to be already installed on the Android devices. So you have chicken and egg situation. The only way to automate an app installation would be when using a connected PC and push the app via adb install to the device, but that requires a computer not a flash drive. As last resort you could send a pre-configured Raspberry Pi to the customers that installs the app via adb.